# INSERT INTO temp table from unknown number and name of columns (from dynamic PIVOT query)

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

I have a dynamic query as shown below. The `@ColumnNames` param has multiple columns this pivot is using. `@ID` and `@Apartment_ID` come from insert parameters.

```
SET @DynamicSQL = 'select id, name, address, phone, remarks, ' + **@ColumnNames** + ' 
                   from  (select b.id, name, criteria_id, impact_value, remarks  
                          from dbo.User u
                          inner join dbo.ID b on b.id = u.id
                          where b.Instance_ID = '+ **@Id**  + 
                           'and ownerID in (select * from fnSplitString(''' +   **@Apartment_ID**  + + ''',' + ''','''       + '))'              
              + ') as t  
              pivot (max(impact_value) for criteria_id in (' + **@ColumnNames**+')
              ) pivoted '

Exec sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

will be get a result as shown in the screenshot. The columns (91, 92,..) are not fixed that get from `@ColumnNames`:

[image: image description here]

I want to insert this dynamic result set into temp table to make sorts function.

```
Declare @SQLstrs nvarchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempResult') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempResult  

CREATE TABLE #tempResult 
(  
     id int,
     name nvarchar(max),
     address nvarchar(max),
     phone nvarchar(max),
     Remarks nvarchar(max),
     **@ColumnNames**
)

--EXEC (@Alter_sql);

SET @SQLstrs = 'Insert into #tempResult ' + @DynamicSQL 

EXEC @SQLstrs
```

Since temp table need to include the fixed columns, how can I set up the dynamic columns that can't know how many columns will be insert ?

Comment: What does this mean - *"I want to insert this dynamic result set into temp table to make sorts function."*? This sounds very much like [an xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361) to me.

Comment: What exactly do you plan to do with `#tempResult` table then?

Comment: I want to make order by name from temp table cause I tried it before inserting order by statement inside the @DynamicSQL didn't work. Thats why, first put the dynamic data into temp table without sorting. Then making sorting with temp table

Comment: You can add order by to Dynamic SQL - what do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you get an error? Did you not get the results you were expecting?  It should be something like -  `pivot (max(impact_value) for criteria_id in (' + @ColumnNames+')) pivoted ORDER BY pivoted.name, pivoted.address'`

Comment: @GarethD thanks for suggest. But its still didn't work and showed error like, column name are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `select into`

```
 SET @SQLstrs = 'select * into #tempResult from(' + @DynamicSQL  +') as _temp'
```

Comment: how can I mentioned about columns name before ?

Comment: you do not need to create table #tempResult before,"select into " will create the table automatically

Comment: Thanks. but I try to use this query but when exec the @SQLstrs , didn't show up the result table . as I m newbie please suggest how should I need to do ? thanks alot.

Comment: It didn't show up the table because you did not ·select·  it, After ·EXEC @SQLstrs· ,you should `select * from #tempResult` to see the result

Comment: @prance, If you create the local temporary table dynamically using `SELECT * INTO #tempResult...` it will be out of scope for the parent session, you would have to use a global temporary table - `SELECT * INTO ##tempResult ...`. If you do this though, you encounter concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks for help. but it still didn't show up the same result as table from @DynamicSQL when select out the temp table :(

Comment: As @GarethD mentioned ,try using global temporary table,to avoid concurrency issues,consider using `newID()` as part of the temporary table name